# Photo uploading using Google Map SDK iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk

I need to upload an image to google map from my iOS app.
In [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps) we can upload image in review section.
I go through the Google documentation and I can't find one.

Is it possible to upload an image to maps using iOS SDK for Google Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no api for that, even the [Place Photos service](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) is just a read-only api. That means you can only view photos from places, but not adding them to Google Maps directly from your app.